# Big-O Notation and Time Complexity Confusion

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Our teacher gave us this group homework about time complexity analysis.

> An algorithm takes 100 seconds to process 5000 data, if it takes 2400 to process 400000 data, what is the time complexity approximation of this algorithm? (In big-O Notation)

We've made this python script to approximate the big-O notation.

```py
import math
def O(n):
    return (n**(1/4))*(math.log(n, 2)**5)

print(O(400000)/O(5000)) # Prints 23.82907726248897 this is the best approximation we've got
```

Moreover, we've discussed really far, about some of these notation, are these the same?

- O(2^n) and O(3^n)
- O(n^k) and O(n^(k+1))
- O(n^(1/2)) and O(n^(1/3))

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is not answerable with the information given; time complexity is about the limit as n goes to infinity, so two finite data points don't determine the time complexity. Even ignoring that, there are very many different functions which would give these two outputs. Your teacher seems to be promoting a misconception here.

Comment: Sorry, but that's *not* a good approximation. As others have already pointed out, the correct answer is that there is no answer. If you are only given two data points, it could be any of O(log n), O(n log n), O(n), O(n^2), O(2^n), or theoretically even O(1) - just by tweaking the constant factor and adding a constant. But `O((n**(1/4))*(math.log(n, 2)**5))` without any further information, while of course possible, like any other function, seems extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approximation for your group homework is good enough. Nice work! But people seldom analyze their programs in a black-box manner (count time and approximate) since people always know the algorithm and implementation. So don't take the homework too seriously ;)

And the following notation pairs, as you mentioned, are indeed different:

- O(2^n) and O(3^n)
- O(n^k) and O(n^(k+1))
- O(n^(1/2)) and O(n^(1/3))

Each pair of notations has a non-negligible gap between each other.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Kaya3, this is indeed a poor question, which cannot really be answered without more data and/or algorithm description.

Assuming a power model, T(n) = a n^k, we solve and get k = log(80)/log(24) ~ 1.379.